# svn command to see changes before update

Tags: svn

I once passed through an svn command that lists the file changes and/or log messages for the HEAD repository. So that you can see what will be updated in my local  repository before I run an `svn update` command. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean:
 `svn status --show-updates`.

You can see more information about it in:

- [SVNBook | See an overview of your changes](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.examine.status),
- [SVNBook | `svn status`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html).

Comment: This would tell me the changes I am going to commit. I want to know the changes that would occur to my working copy from HEAD when i do update.

Comment: Nah, I think Marc is right: from the linked manual: "--show-updates (-u)
Causes the client to display information about which files in your working copy are out of date. This doesn't actually update any of your files— **it just shows you which files will be updated if you then use svn update**." -- If I remember correctly, this is what i.e. Eclipse does when you tell it to Team>Synchronize...

Comment: @UmairR Marc is right about using `svn update --show-updates`. BTW, TortoiseSVN has a GUI for this: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-wcstatus.html#tsvn-dug-wcstatus-dia-2 (see "check repository" button.

Comment: I don't have svn in this pc, but it may be: svn log --limit NUM  (Where NUM is the number of logs you want to list). If you want more info about the svn log command you can visit: [visualsvn](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svn/#svn.ref.svn.sw.limit)